# Generate report depending on connected user

Tags: sql, sharepoint, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

We have product manager and territory manager. The product manager can see his own product on all territory. The territory manager can see all product on his own territory.

I want to generate a report for each case, and then share it with the manager.

My data source is actually an sql server database that contains in one table all the information

```
Product A | SubProduct A |  Location A |    SellAmount1 
Product A | SubProduct B |  Location A |    SellAmount2 
Product B | SubProduct A |  Location A |    SellAmount3 
Product B | SubProduct B |  Location A |    SellAmount4 
Product A | SubProduct A |  Location B |    SellAmount5 
Product A | SubProduct B |  Location B |    SellAmount6 
Product B | SubProduct A |  Location B |    SellAmount7 
Product B | SubProduct B |  Location B |    SellAmount8
```

So if the territory manager A is connected, I've to show only this information

```
Product A | SubProduct A |  Location A |    SellAmount1 
Product A | SubProduct B |  Location A |    SellAmount2 
Product B | SubProduct A |  Location A |    SellAmount3 
Product B | SubProduct B |  Location A |    SellAmount4
```

And if the product manager B is connected, I've to show this

```
Product B | SubProduct A |  Location A |    SellAmount3
Product B | SubProduct B |  Location A |    SellAmount4
Product B | SubProduct A |  Location B |    SellAmount7
Product B | SubProduct B |  Location B |    SellAmount8
```

I'm trying to achieve this by using Microsoft tools. We are using a sharepoint site, and I've try to generate report with SSRS, report builder...

I can create the full report, but I'have no idea how to manage the report for the manager.

Any advice, information is welcome!

Damien

### UPDATE

I need to have something like this, and add an application to fill the member, memberLocation and memberProduct table.

[image: How to manage user in ssrs]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dataset based on a parameter called Manager('Product Manager','Territory Manager'). In dataset put "where" condition that filters correct your data.

The parameter manager can be updated based on user connected with help of built-in parametr User!UserID.

Comment: Is this the only way to do that? I was hoping there will be some built'in feature to manage that more simple. I will update my question with a graphic to be more precise. Thanks